# DNS server failed & scapy DNS response

Tags: python, powershell, networking, dns, scapy

I have a server and client set up, the server will send DNS **TXT** response packets (authoritative) via **Scapy** to the client, when the client queries the domain, and the client is supposed to receive the response and store it into a variable.

The client queries via PowerShell, and the server responses via Scapy in Python.

However, when the client queries the domain, the server sends out the response packets, but the client does not receive it and only returns "Server Failed" error in less than a second (even setting the timeout to be 20 seconds).

It can be ruled out that it is the python server's fault in sending the response packet, as online tools receive the authoritative DNS response with no errors.

And when I setup a web server on the domain, I am able to access it.

The command used in PowerShell script

```
$response = nslookup -query=TXT -timeout=20 blah.blah.org
```

The error when querying

```
*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find blah.blah.org: Server failed
```

How can I resolve this issue of not receiving the DNS TXT response from my server to client?

***** SORRY, forgot to mention, I am using PowerShell v2.0 for testing purposes *****

Comment: What do you get if you use [DNS.Resolve()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of nslookup?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using PowerShell v2.0 for testing purposes, so there is no Resolve-DnsName function :)

Comment: Wasn't talking about using resolve-dnsname, meant using the .NET [DNS] class's Resolve() method.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Ok, so I tried the .NET [DNS] class's Resolve() method, and it returned the error " This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server"

Comment: so it thinks it can't find an authoritative server, I'm guessing some portion of what windows expects as a DNS response is missing.  can you use wireshark to capture and compare the response you receive from a normal DNS server and then compare to responses from your scapy server?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I ran wireshark, and tested 3 scenarios (TXT record), 
 1: nslookup stackoverflow.com, no errors
 2: nslookup mydomain.org, (with python server running on domain IP), got SERVFAIL
 3: nslookup mydomain.org, (with python server running on localhost), no errors, got Authoritative response (from localhost python server) via 8.8.8.8